# How do I append values to a ...interface{}?

Tags: go, interface

Here's a sample function I want to emulate:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Initially I want %d %s", 2, "dogs"))
    fmt.Println(Sprintf2("Now I want %d %s", 2, "dogs"))
}

func Sprintf2(format string, a ...interface{}) string {

return fmt.Sprintf(format + " and %d cats", append(a, 5))
}
```

here's a link in playground: https://play.golang.org/p/dHDwTlbRLDu

expected output:

> Initially I want 2 dogs
>   Now I want 2 dogs and 5 cats

actual output:

> Initially I want 2 dogs 
>   Now I want [2 %!d(string=dogs) 5] %!s(MISSING) and %!d(MISSING) cats

Comment: `a = append(a, myValue)`

Comment: that didn't work as expected:
https://play.golang.org/p/dHDwTlbRLDu

Comment: That's because you're not doing exactly what you requested in your question. Create a `[]interface{}` variable, add your variables to that, then unpack it (`...`) when calling Sprintf.

Comment: Edits made. That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first append your new value to the `a` slice, and then unpack the slice when calling `fmt.Sprintf`:

```
func Sprintf2(format string, a ...interface{}) string {
    a = append(a, 5)
    return fmt.Sprintf(format+" and %d cats", a...)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/YRWzAT2Yxm_q